# Inexperienced beginner doesn't understand error message on msprep

Tags: r

I am trying to teach myself some survival analysis in RStudio. At present I am stuck on the msprep function. I get the error message "Error in msprep(time = c(NA, "c1t", "l1t"), status = c(NA, "c1", "l1"),  : missing "data" argument not allowed when time argument is character vector."

Here is my script containing the msprep command:

```
library(dplyr)
library(mstate)

load(file="hepatocellular.Rdata")

number <- hepatocellular$number
death <- hepatocellular$death
recurrence <- hepatocellular$recurrence
competing <- hepatocellular$competing
X_t <- hepatocellular$X_t
X_d <- hepatocellular$X_d
afp <- hepatocellular$afp
tumorsize <- hepatocellular$tumorsize
cxcl17p <- hepatocellular$cxcl17p


hc <- data.frame(number, death, recurrence, X_t, competing, X_d,
                 afp, tumorsize, cxcl17p)

hc <- hc %>% mutate(d1 = case_when(competing == 1 ~ '1',
                                   competing > 1 ~ '0')) 
hc$d1 <- as.numeric(hc$d1)
hc$d1t <- hc$X_t
# hc <- hc %>% mutate(d1t = case_when(d1 == 0 ~ '0'))
# hc$d1t <- as.numeric(hc$d1t)

 hc <- hc %>% mutate(c1 = case_when(competing == 2 ~ '1',
                                   competing == 1 ~ '0',
                                   competing == 3 ~ '0'))
 hc$c1 <- as.numeric(hc$c1)

# hc <- hc %>% mutate(c1t = case_when(c1 == 1 ~ X_t,
#                                    c1 == 0 ~ 0))
 hc$c1t <- hc$X_t

 hc <- hc  %>% mutate(l1 = case_when(competing == 3 ~ '1',
                                    competing < 3 ~ '0'))
 hc$l1 <- as.numeric(hc$l1)
# hc <- hc %>% mutate(l1t = case_when(l1 == 1 ~ X_t,
#                                    l1 == 0 ~ 0))
# hc$l1t <- as.numeric(hc$l1t)
hc$l1t <- hc$X_t
 
hc$compword <- factor(hc$competing,
                      levels = c(1, 2, 3),
                      labels = c("Death", 
                                 "Cancer recurs but lives", 
                                 "Lives and cancer did not recur")
              )  

 hc.w <- crprep("X_t", "competing", data=hc, trans=c("Cancer recurs but lives",
                           "Lives and cancer did not recur"),
                            cens="X_d", id="number")

# calculate cause-specific cumulative incidence, no truncation,
# compare with Cuminc (also from mstate)
 ciA <- Cuminc(hc$X_t, hc$competing)
 sfA <- survfit(Surv(Tstart,Tstop,status=="Cancer recurs but lives")~1, 
              data=hc.w, weight=weight.cens, subset=failcode=="Cancer recurs but lives")

# plot(sf, fun="event", mark.time=FALSE)
# lines(CI.2~time,data=ciA,type="s",col="red")

  sfA <- survfit(Surv(Tstart,Tstop,status=="Lives and cancer did not recur")~1, 
         data=hc.w, weight=weight.cens, subset=failcode=="Lives and cancer did not recur")
  
# plot(sf, fun="event", mark.time=FALSE)
#  lines(CI.2~time,data=ciA,type="s",col="maroon3")
#  lines(CI.3~time,data=ci,type="s",col="red")

# surv <- ciA$Surv
# time <- ciA$time
# CI.2 <- ciA$CI.2
# CI.3 <- ciA$CI.3
 
#  plot(time, surv, type = "s", col = "red", lwd=2)
#  lines(time, CI.2,type="s",col="maroon3", lwd = 3)
#  lines(time, CI.3,type="s",col="orange2", lwd = 3)
 


 tmat <- trans.comprisk(2, names = c("Death", "Cancer recurs but lives",
                                     "Lives and cancer did not recur"))
 

 hepato.long <- msprep(time = c(NA, 'c1t', 'l1t'),
           status = c(NA, 'c1', 'l1'),
           keep = data.frame('afp', 'tumorsize', 'cxcl17p'),
           trans = tmat)

# drops <- c(hc$l1n)
# hc[ , !(names(hc) %in% drops)]
 
#  print(class(hc$d1t))
#  print(class(hc$c1t))
#  print(class(hc$l1t))
type here
```

My model for composing this function was the example on p. 131 in "Applied Survival Analysis using R" by Dirk Moore 2016. I have tried making various changes to the time and status arguments, but have run out of ideas. Can anybody tell me why my msprep isn't working?

The msprep worked if I omit the 'keep =' line. Here is an example of output:
An object of class 'msdata'

```
Data:
    id from to trans Tstart Tstop time status
1    1    1  2     1      0     2    2      0
2    1    1  3     2      0     2    2      1
3    2    1  2     1      0     2    2      0
4    2    1  3     2      0     2    2      1
5    3    1  2     1      0     2    2      0
```

Answer (score 0):

What the error is trying to tell you is this: You set your `time` argument to a character vector (`c(...)`), indicating column names that reference columns in the data frame (instead of directly providing the values here), which would then require a `data` argument to be present as well (that the column names reference to), but you never set any `data` argument. You need to pass the relevant data frame as `data` argument. See [docs](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/mstate/versions/0.3.2/topics/msprep).

Comment: That's great, much appreciated. I now get new error message "argument 'keep' has incorrect dimension". Are you able to tell me what the problem is here?

Comment: How does your line look like now?

Comment: Please see original posting for my response - new lines added at the end. Thanks.

Comment: I've worked it out. I changed 'keep' to 'keep = hc[, 7:9]'  Thanks for your help.